# Getting probability result with scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm currently using the `LinearSVC` module included in `scikit-learn`, which contains a function called `decision_function`, which is meant to return a confidence score.

Is there any way of using this to get some kind of percentage confidence for display to the user? And how do I point it to get the confidence for returning a given label?

Comment: Cheers, the code there answered my question!